# Roughly how old was L?

Tags: character, death-note

When L and Soichiro are surveying the Yagami household L says. "When I was young I did strange things too", which indicated that he is considerably older than Light was at the time (17). However he is able to pass off as a student in Light's final exam. He was old enough, clearly to have been training Near to be a detective for what could have been near's whole life (13) so just how old was L?

Comment: [The same question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29618/how-old-was-l-in-the-death-note-series) is present in the Anime and Manga Stack Exchange, check this out! :)

Comment: @Ikaros Just appeared 9 hours late there :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L's age was not mentioned in anime but in the prequel light novel [Death Note Another Note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note_Another_Note:_The_Los_Angeles_BB_Murder_Cases), his age was mentioned as 22.

<sub>I don't have screenshot of night novel with me now, will try to come up with it if found any.</sub>

So his age in the main Manga/Anime is speculated to be 24-25. Same guess is present in [deathnote.wikia.com](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/L_(character)).